# Unable to access json as static file through golang server

Tags: go

I am trying to serve json files using golang FileServer but it is not working.
For better understand, please refer below code snippet.

```
func main() {
  // There is json file present in directory ui/web/data.json
  // This handler is working fine and I am able to access json file 
  // through /data.json
  http.Handle("/", http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("ui/web"))))

  // There is another json file in ui/data directory ui/data/user.json.
  // Below handler is not wokring and I am unable to access user.json file at
  // /d/user.json
  http.Handle("/d", http.StripPrefix("/d", http.FileServer(http.Dir("ui/data"))))

  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil))
}
```

I am not getting the point why first handler is working fine but second handler is not working.

Comment: `"ui/web"` and `"ui/data"` are relative paths, they will be resolved to the **working directory**. Make sure they are correct (you can test with absolute path to make sure). Also there's no need to strip `/`.

Comment: I wasn't aware that strict slash is required but this works
http.Handle("/d/", http.StripPrefix("/d/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("ui/data"))))

Answer (score 0):

I got the error which is actually not an error. I have to put / after 'd' in path.

```
http.Handle("/d", http.StripPrefix("/d", http.FileServer(http.Dir("ui/data"))))
```

above code should be like this:

```
http.Handle("/d/", http.StripPrefix("/d/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("ui/data"))))
```

It solved the problem.